# How to add click event to an element with JQuery which is created by serverside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create an `ul` list in serverside as you can see the below. I want to add click event to `a` elements with jquery but I can't access any elements. Here my codes:

Server side:

```
 StringBuilder sbSubCitchens = new StringBuilder();

 sbSubCitchens.Append(@"<div id=""content_1"" class=""subCats"">");
 sbSubCitchens.Append("<ul>");

foreach (kitchen kitchen in kitchenList)
 {
    sbSubCitchens.Append(@"<li><a  class="" " + kitchen.KitchenId + @""">" + kitchen.Name + "</a>  </li>");
 }
 sbSubCitchens.Append("</ul>");
 sbSubCitchens.Append("</div>");

 ltrKitchenList.Text = sbSubCitchens.ToString();
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $(".mCSB_container ul li a").click(function () {
       // do smth...
    });
})
```

Html output :

```
<div class="mCSB_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
  <ul>
   <li><a class=" 1">Cafe</a>  </li>
   <li><a class=" 2">Dünya Mutfağı</a>  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that html output is correct? Because according to the server-side code you posted, the class on the `div` would be `subCats`, not `mCSB_container`.

Comment: I Don't know asp.net but those strings don't look right to me, I think you either need to escape the inner quotes or you use single quotes for the outer quotes

Comment: @andrew The @ symbol before the string means you don't need to escape quotes - you just put them twice instead (like old-skool basic :)

Comment: @A.Wolff The links exist at document.ready as they're created server-side :)

Comment: @andrew the @ symbol allows you to have certain characters in the string literal (like backslashes or newlines) without escaping them. Escaping double quotes is done by doubling them up, as he has done. Also, in .net, single quotes are only for `char`s, not strings. So his strings are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".mCSB_container ul li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do smth...
});
```

I think the click may be working, but since you aren't preventing the default action, the link may be reloading the page.

Also make sure the html output is what you expect, since the server-side code you posted, by itself, won't give you the output you posted (and therefore the selector wouldn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put the "href" parameter:

```
<a href="#" class="whatever">Some stuff</a>
```